# Sharing paid apps between two devices

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account

I've checked the posts saying how a paid Google app can be shared between two devices, but no-one says how to do it. There's all this stuff about using the same Google account, but what does that mean - it takes me no further.

Can anyone help please with easy-to-follow explanation?

Answer (score 3):

You need to link your two devices together with a Google account. Done, hope this helped!

Okay, I'm not going to be that guy...

Here's how to really do it:

1. Open your Settings app.
2. Scroll down to find an option called something like Accounts and tap on it.
3. Now find an option that says Add account.
4. Now click the type of account, in this case, a Google account.
5. Now sign in with the same info used to initially buy the app or game.
6. When you're done, go into Google Play and swipe right to enter the options for the app, or click on the three-line-symbol in the top left.
7. Click on your current account to switch it out, now click on the account you just added.
8. Find the application you previously bought, and it will say Purchased.
9. Download and complete!

Comment: Hmmm... I tried this, and it did not work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't search the app, go to the menu and My Apps and Games, then Library. You can install from there without paying again.